# SOS:Streaming video from android camera to VLC player on PC

Tags: android, vlc, live555

I am in search of some code that streams the live camera recording of android device to the vlc player on system.
that means your android device camera is on and you are capturing video and simultaneously when you start vlc player that video is played on camera

any help will be great and please provide me some code if possible

thanks

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

Really, no need to provide details about it. It's open-source and it just works.

Comment: Unfortunately not available anymore on the Play store.

Comment: It is still available on F-Droid as of 2022-December.  Though it is still the 2016 version, it still works on my Google Pixel 3.

(F-Droid is an alternative to Google Play store which hosts only free and open-source apps.  Download and install the F-Droid app from the website www.f-droid.org (you need to temporarily allow your web browser --Chrome or whatever-- to install apps).  Now you have access to a whole host of other Android apps you never knew existed. )